# almost surely randomly chosen number from [0,1] has every possible finite string in decimal expansion

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We say number is cosmic if in it's decimal expansion there are every possible finite strings of numbers. Prove that almost surely (with probability 1) randomly chosen number from $[0,1]$ is cosmic.

My solution:

Fix arbitrary string, it has some length, let's say $k$. Let $A_1$ be event that randomly chosen number from $[0,1]$ has this string in first $k$ places (for example if our string was 2312 then our number has to be for example $0,2312943(1)$ or $0.2312(0)$, in general let $A_n$ be event that randomly chosen number from $[0,1]$ has this string starting at place $(n-1)k+1$ and ending at place $nk$.

$$P(A_n)=(\frac{1}{10})^k$$

Events $A_i$ are independent.

$$\sum_{1}^{\infty}P(A_n)=\infty$$

From Borel-Cantelli: almost surely randomly chosen number from $[0,1]$ has in it's decimal expansion chosen string infinitely many times.

Because string was arbitrary we have that: almost surely randomly chosen number from $[0,1]$ has in it's decimal expansion every possible finite string (infinitely many times).

Is this proof okay? I am not sure because I proved even more than I needed, but I can't spot mistake.

Edit. What is the sample space here? Is it countably infinite product of sets {$0,1,...,9$}?

Comment: I edited my post. What is the sample space here? Is it countably infinite product of sets {0,1,...,9}
?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number)? If I understand cosmic numbers correctly, normal numbers are cosmic, but not all cosmic numbers are normal.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. It shows that for every finite string $s$, the event that $s$ occurs infinitely often in the decimal expansion has probability $1$. To go further and conclude that almost surely *every* string occurs infinitely often in the decimal expansion, you need two additional results:

1. The set of all finite strings is countable.
2. The probability of the intersection of a countable number of events is $1$ if each event has probability $1$.

Comment: Why do I need this?

Comment: You have shown $P(A_s)=1$ for each $s$, where $A_s$ is the event that $s$ occurs in the decimal expansion. You are asked to prove $P(\bigcap_s  A_s)=1$.

Comment: But s is arbitrary, doesn't it imply that every string occurs? In your version, intersection is taken for all finite strings?

Comment: If an event $A_i$ has probability $1$ for each index $i$, the intersection event $\bigcap_i A_i$ need not have probability $1$. Think of selecting a number uniformly from the interval $[0,1]$, and let $A_x$ be the event that the number $x$ is not selected. Then $P(A_x)=1$ but $P(\bigcap_x A_x)=0$.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.